# why is c++ opening my windows terminal and VS Code terminal?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

Whenever I ask for the user input (using C or C++), VS Code will open my windows terminal, ask for input, and then close and ask for the same input in the integrated VSC terminal.

Now, this should be a very simple fix but no matter what I google, I can't find anyone having the same issue.

[image: Terminal Opening]

[image: Same input being asked in VSC Terminal]

Also, when I enter input into the windows terminal, it doesn't use that information at all. It just closes after all of the console input operations are complete. Only the VS Code's integrated terminal does anything useful.

Anyways, does anyone know how I can disable my windows terminal from opening up when running C/C++ programs?

Tried googling for help but couldn't find anything directly related to what I was experiencing

Comment: This is not C++ issue. It is more like undesired configuration of VS Code (or some plugin problem).

Comment: I figured, I can't find anything to indicate why this is happening though. Hopefully someone who has also had this issue can comment

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see the instructions on creating an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).